# Вывод 3-х разных записей

Tags: php, mysql

Как вывести 3 разных записи из базы данных, только 3 и разных, то есть:
в бд есть 4 записи:

```
Запись 1 
Запись 2 
Запись 3 
Запись 4
```

Нужно сделать так что бы выводились только 3 записи и разные.
Запросы и т.д на mysqli

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 3;` - пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал, так у меня одни и те же 3 записи выводятся.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев вам нужно чтоб дублирующиеся записи игнорировались?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам уже ответили... Если немного подумаете то придете к

```
Select * from table where status = 'top' LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

Comment: зачем мне рандом? если мне нужно вывести определенные записи 
Select * from `table` where `status` = 'top' 
нужно что бы их вывело 3 не больше, если 2 записи со значением top то выведет 2...

Comment: Окей тогда поясни свой вопрос.
Ты хочешь выводить 3 записи и 3 разных? LIMIT 3 -- решение для 3-х записей.
Затем ты отвечаешь что в этом случае у тебя выводятся одни и те же 3 записи. ORDER BY RAND() -- отсортирует список случайным образом из записей, которые будут удовлетворять условиям, а LIMIT 3 выведет только первые 3 из этого списка.

Таким образом, предложенный мною запрос будет выводить 3 случайных записи из таблицы table!

Comment: Вы опять мне не поняли, зачем мне случайные записи??? Мне нужно вывести 3 записи с WHERE `status` = 'top'

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE status='top' LIMIT 3; -- так советовал @ua6xh